# Does this say petitioner can make the decision on info discussed previous to this sentence, but after resolution doesn't apply to her decision?

Tags: terminology

After conferring with each other concerning the foregoing matters, if the parties do not reach an agreement upon any such matter, Petitioner shall have the descretion to make the decision and the provision hereinafter set forth concerning resolution of disputes shall not apply to her decision.

Comment: What were the *foregoing* matters? It matters if you're Respondent.

Comment: That she has the final decision on schools, religious instruction, healthcare etc.

Comment: That means her decisions on the enumerated things can't be appealed (e.g. if she decides they are going to attend the new church up the road or no church at all, she does not need your permission).

Comment: Does this sentence state that when it comes to the rest of the decree the disputes shall not apply to her decision? Like visition etc.

Comment: Any matter that isn't enumerated before the sentence beginning "after conferring" is not a foregoing matter. The one to watch for is can she relocate without appeal. You **need** an attorney, I'd love to help; but it varies by region, and I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I feel more confident about hiring an attorney at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I see it as

1) if the parties do not agree in the conference, the Petitioner gets to make the decision.

2) if she does so, this decision is final and not subject to appeal.

Makes you wonder when the provision for resolution DOES apply, because in the other case everyone agreed and there should be no disputes!

Comment: For other matters, e.g. not the *foregoing* matters.

Comment: Everyone agreed to what was written prior to that sentence. But the decree doesn't end there. So does that mean that the information discussed afterward could be disputed in court?

Comment: @user65095 You don't have an English question, you have a legal question. Ask your attorney.

Comment: Just thought I might get some help prior to paying an attorney $3500.

Comment: @user65095 Negotiate up front! Do not give them a massive retainer and carte blanche.

Comment: Usually you can get advice for less than a full case.

Comment: Oldcat has the bare meaning of it here, and I would most certainly not sign anything with that clause in it if I was the respondent unless perhaps my solicitor had given me a very good explanation of why it wasn't as worrisome as it seems.